# How to create reset() method in Service that return promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I've got a service called `MyArticles`. Using `$http GET`, collects all articles for a given Category. The `MyArticles` Service is injected in `ControllerA`, `ControllerB`, `ControllerC`, that should run some commands after `MyArticles Promise` is resolved.

Works after first initialisation, but I don't know what to do if I need to reset() the loaded data for MyArticles, since the commands in the `ControllerA, ControllerB, ControllerC` only runs the first time, after the promise is resolved. For example, what if I'd like to get Articles from a different Category ?

I'm trying to find a pattern for this and I wrote the following,  I guess it helps to understand what I'd like to achieve:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.config(function($locationProvider){

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

});

MyApp.factory('MyService', function($q,$timeout){

    var deferred;

    var loadData = function(){

        deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve({ 
                myData: "test"
            });
        }, 250);

    };

    return {

        reset: function(){

            loadData();

        },

        getPromise: function(){

            return deferred.promise;

        }

    };

});

MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,MyService){

  $scope.foo = "Service share data";

  MyService.reset();

  MyService.getPromise().then(function(data){

        console.log(data);

  });

});
```

*the example is also available at: http://jsbin.com/OCaNehe/2/

I wonder what I can do, if I need a service - using promises - that should be able to refresh data and the service is being injected in different Controllers, etc ?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: If you want to resolve with different values after each other, a Promise is the wrong pattern as it only represents a single value. Look into something like streams :-) Or simply implement the observer pattern, which is built-in angular already…

Comment: @Bergi thanks for looking! I'll be searching about streams :) And of course, I'll get to the observer pattern

Comment: @Bergi actually, I'm now wondering what to do in the controllers, if I can't use the promise pattern. I can only run the commands if the data is available. I'm going try the $watch but not sure if it's going to work! Thanks a lot

Comment: I've created this example http://jsbin.com/epAMaP/1 but I'm not sure if this will solve my problem. I still think I'll need to use promise and to share and trigger data in other directives and controllers, I'm thinking about using $emit, $broadcast and $on. I'm not seeing another way around this!

Comment: @Bergi I opened a new topic and I think I got the answer for my problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128660/how-share-service-dynamic-data-between-controllers-and-directives/19128863#19128863 ). Hope this may be helpful for someone in the future.

Comment: I think it would've been more appropriate to post the answer under this topic here, but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is to use watches. See: http://plnkr.co/edit/auovRxGPViyflUVPvG1A?p=preview. It might be easier to maintain compared to $emit/$broadcasts later on, especially if you end up having tons of services along with directives and controllers that use them.

Also you might want to think about using the natural scope inheritance angular has, but that depends on your application.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time! This is awesome! I've been studying it and looks, like you said, as a better solution!

Comment: according to this (http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html) it mentions that we shouldn't use $watch inside controllers ?!

Comment: He is trying to say that most things in controllers don't require a watch like directives do. However there's nothing wrong with putting watches in controllers. In this case, you are doing it because you want to share data across multiple controllers. In my opinion, a project should never need many controllers or much code in the controllers. Most code can categorize into directives and services. There are also other ways you can share the data that depend on the structure of your project that may be better (scope hierarchies, directive scope, etc).

Comment: thanks for your knowledge! I did liked the way you solved this issue, it looks very clean. I don't really have that many controllers, but I do share a Service between Controllers, Directives, etc.