# How share Service dynamic data between Controllers and Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, observer-pattern, promise, angularjs-service

I'd like to know what pattern to use, if I need my Service to share its dynamic data between Controller, Directives, etc. The reason I mention dynamic, is because I'd like to load new data and this data needs to be available in any other Controller, Directive, etc. For example, if a Directive generates a UL LI, it would have to re-generate it if the data inside the Service has changed!

I initially opened [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126172/how-to-create-reset-method-in-service-that-return-promise) and someone suggested that I should use the Observer Pattern. I wrote [this code](http://jsbin.com/epAMaP/1) very quickly as a spike of what I need to do.

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.config(function($locationProvider){

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

});

MyApp.factory('MyService', function($timeout){
    
    var data;

    var loadData = function(){

        data = {
            foo: "bar",
            time: new Date()
        };

        return data;

    };

    return {

        refresh: function(){

            loadData();

        },

        getData: function(){
            
            return loadData();

        }

    };

});

MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,MyService,$timeout){
    
  $scope.foo = "Service share data";
 
  $scope.data = MyService.getData();

  $scope.$on("eventFoo", function(){
    console.log("Data has changed!");
    console.log($scope.data);
  });

  $timeout(function(){
    MyService.refresh();
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.data = MyService.getData();

        $scope.$emit("eventFoo");
    });
  }, 3000);

});

MyApp.directive('myDirective', function(MyService,$timeout){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.$on("eventFoo", function(){
                console.log("Event foo triggered!");

                scope.data = MyService.getData();

                console.log(scope.data);
            });
        }
    };

});
```

I think this would solve most of my problems but there's something that I need to remember. The data that I'll load comes from `$http` GET, so I think that I need to use at least a promise every time I need to update or load data, then trigger the right event.

My lack of experience with AngularJs drives me to question my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a possible answer, using promise and the Observer Pattern (if this is correct and describes what I'm doing):

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.config(function($locationProvider){

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

});

MyApp.factory('MyService', function($q,$timeout,$rootScope){
    
    var deferred;
    var data;

    var loadData = function(){

        data = {
            foo: "bar" +  Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1),
            time: new Date()
        };

        deferred.resolve(data);

    };

    return {

        getPromise: function(){

            deferred = $q.defer();
            loadData();

            return deferred.promise;

        },

        getData: function(){
            
            return data;

        }

    };

});

MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,MyService,$timeout){
    
  $scope.foo = "Service share data";
 
  MyService.getPromise().then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log("Initial data request:");
    console.log($scope.data);
    $scope.$emit("eventFoo");
  });

  // then after awhile a user requests updated data
  $timeout(function(){

    console.log("// then after awhile a user requests updated data");

    $scope.$apply(function(){

        MyService.getPromise().then(function(data){

            $scope.data = MyService.getData();
            $scope.$emit("eventFoo");

        });         

    });
  }, 3000);

});

MyApp.directive('myDirective', function(MyService,$timeout){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.$on("eventFoo", function(){
                console.log("Event foo triggered!");

                scope.data = MyService.getData();

                console.log(scope.data);
            });
        }
    };

});
```

You can find the code live at http://jsbin.com/ahiYiBu/1/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I recently shared data between two controllers and a service by using

`$rootScope.$broadcast` to fire and 
`$scope.$on` to catch changes

as far as I can tell it is Angular's implementation of the observer pattern